# Android spinner dropdown issue

Tags: android

I have created an app which will retrieve the data from the web server.My app when when launched just shows the spinner dropdown menu is not visible.I think the issue is with the main activity i have also placed the url in the config file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements       Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> trips;
private JSONArray result;
public static String SYSTEM_ID;
public static String CUSTOMER_ID;
public static String USER_ID;
public static String TRIP_TYPE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    trips= new ArrayList<String>();
    this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadtrip();
}
public void loadtrip() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        j = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(SYSTEM_ID, "12");
            params.put(CUSTOMER_ID, "3513");
            params.put(USER_ID, "124");
            params.put(TRIP_TYPE, "Open");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            trips.add(json.getString(config.DATA_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trips));
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, trips);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

try following code

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/ check this link for reference

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, It will help you:

```
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

It's working for me